# How can an SSH attempt be canceled if the connection is taking over N seconds to establish a connection?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've got a deploy script that uses SSH to connect to a number of hosts.  Occasionally, a host will be under such severe load that the ssh attempt will hang. This will eventually cause a timeout in the deploy, but only after a very long period of time.

Ideally, I'd like the script to fail faster than the 20 minute timeout.

Is there a way to detect that the SSH connection hasn't been made after a certain period of time, so I could then cancel the attempt in a more controlled fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to looked into setting a connection timeout via `ConnectTimeout` like this:

```
-o ConnectTimeout=1200
```

As the man page for [`ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) options states:

> Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the SSH server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout. This value is used only when the target is down or really unreachable, not when it refuses the connection.

So it would look something like this in usage:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1200 someone@example.com
```

FWIW, the`ConnectTimeout` value—like many things in scripts like this—is set in a value in seconds. So 1200 seconds equates 20 minutes